# ASP.NET MVC Razor - All form fields are required?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, jquery-validate, required

I have a form that is generated by ASP.NET. 
I have some required fields, and I am using the [Required] dataAnnotation for that. 
However, the elements that don't have the [Required] DataAnnotation are also required according to my webpage. These are not required at all yet I cannot submit the form if they are empty.

I used scaffolding to make the pages, jquery validator is used (by default) for the validation.

Model class (some fields have been omitted for clarity)

```
public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the minimum (default) price for this room.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Display(Name = "Minimum price")]
    public decimal MinPrice { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Alternative price")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal AltPrice { get; set; }
}
```

The code that creates the form fields in de .cshtml file:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MinPrice, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MinPrice)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MinPrice)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AltPrice, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AltPrice)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AltPrice)
        </div>
    </div>
```

The required field correctly displays the error message as defined (thus it reads the annotations). 
The non required field displays a generic error message instead ("The Alternative price field is required.").

I've searched quite a lot, but everywhere it says that if the [Required] DataAnnotation is not there, it won't be required in the form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make the non-required fields nullable.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks! I cannot accept the answer yet but I will as soon as I can.

Comment: Then what is the point of [Required] attribute?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. I had to go into my model and put ? marks in the int fields to make them null. The fields that were set as string were fine it was just the int fields that were causing the issue.